# Orthogonality in ANOVA and Regression Analysis

Tags: regression, anova, categorical-encoding, orthogonal

I [read the following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable#Contrast_coding) (Wikipedia) regarding contrast coding of categorical variables:

> Unlike when used in ANOVA, where it is at the researcher’s discretion whether they choose coefficient values that are either orthogonal or non-orthogonal, in regression, it is essential that the coefficient values assigned in contrast coding be orthogonal.

What is the precise notion of **orthogonality** used here? Why is this important and why is it "essential" that in regression the coefficient values are orthogonal?